# MATCH AGAINST unknown column

Tags: php, mysql, search, match-against

I have problems with my searching method, I'm using MATCH AGAINST because it's better than LIKE. For example I have a database full of cities and when I type a city name (for example Moscow) in the input field, there is an error "Unknown column 'Moscow' in 'where clause'". I have two columns in my database, city_id and city_name

[image]

My sql query looks like this

```
"SELECT city_name FROM default_cities WHERE MATCH(city_name) AGAINST($city)"
```

If someone have any suggestions I'll be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"SELECT city_name FROM default_cities WHERE MATCH(city_name) AGAINST('$city')"
```

Use quotes for **$city**

**EDIT**

Don't forget to escape it. (for ex. "l'amour")

Comment: And escape it, even if it's not user-submitted data, because **someone's** going to live in `Coeur d'Alene` or something similar.

Comment: Thank you, I just can't belive what a stupid mistake, but now there is  new error "The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes"

Comment: You have InnoDB table engine but need MyISAM. Maybe you converted it few times ago to InnoDB :)

Comment: What if `$city` is being passed through `POST`?

Comment: This is another question. I just showed author to his mistake. To tell the truth he must use PDO with prepared statements.

Comment: I fixed all my errors but now shows there is no results. Thank you for your help +1

Answer (score 2):

If you posted your *complete* code, we would be able to tell you that you need to put single quotes against `$city`. You should be using prepared statements. I'll also go off on a limb and guess you're using `mysql_` functions. Those are deprecated and you should be using `PDO` or `mysqli_`